# Array index out of bounds error in 2d array during linear search

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, linear-search

I'm writing a program which is suppose to acting like a ticket finder.  It displays a chart of possible seating choices along with their prices and asking if the user would like to select a seat by number or by price.  It works like it's suppose to on the seat by number, but when I try to find a seat by price I get an array index out of bounds error.  I'm confused because it's suppose to be starting a linear search there at zero.  I don't understand why this error is there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindTicket{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String answer="number";
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] seats= {
      {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
      {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
      {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}, 
      {10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10,10}, 
      {10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10,10}, 
      {10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10,10}, 
      {20,20,30,40,40,40,30,30,20,20}, 
      {20,30,30,40,50,50,40,30,30,20},
      {30,40,50,50,50,50,50,50,40,30}
    };

    printChart(seats);
    do{
      System.out.println("Would you like to choose a seat by number, price, or quit?");
      answer = kb.nextLine();
      if(answer.equals("price")){
        sellSeatbyPrice(seats);}
      if(answer.equals("number")){ 
        sellSeatbyNumber(seats);}
      printChart(seats);
    }while(!answer.equals("quit"));
  }

  public static void printChart(int[][] seats){
    for (int i=0; i<seats.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<seats[0].length; j++)
      {
        System.out.printf("%8d", seats[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static int[][] sellSeatbyPrice(int[][] seats){
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int ticketprice;
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    boolean found = false, seatavaliable=true;
    do{
      System.out.println("What is your prefered ticket price?");
      ticketprice=kb.nextInt();
      while (row<seats.length && !found){
        do{
          if(seats[row][col] == ticketprice){
            found = true;}
          else{
            col++; }  
        }while(col<seats[0].length &&!found);
        if(seats[row][col] == ticketprice){
          found = true;}
        else{
          row++;} 
      }
      if(found){
        seats[row][col] = 0; }
      else {
        System.out.println("Seat not found at specified price.");
        seatavaliable=false;}
    }while(seatavaliable==false);

    return seats;
  }

  public static int[][] sellSeatbyNumber(int[][] seats){
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    int editedrow, editedcol;
    boolean seatavaliable = true;
    do{
      System.out.println("What is your prefered seat number?  Please enter row then column.");
      row=kb.nextInt();
      col=kb.nextInt();
      editedrow = 9-row;
      editedcol = col - 1;
      if(seats[editedrow][editedcol] > 0){
        seats[editedrow][editedcol] = 0;}
      else{
        System.out.println("Seat is not avaliable.");
        seatavaliable=false;}
    }while(seatavaliable==false);

    return seats;
  }

}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting your out of bounds error?

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @Michael It says I have an error on 27 and 61.

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth  For my class we have to use JGrasp and we haven't been taught about the debugger.  Is that information online where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `do...while`.

When this block of code is done, col will be greater than the length of your array.

Look at the comments:

```
public static int[][] sellSeatbyPrice(int[][] seats){
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int ticketprice;
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    boolean found = false, seatavaliable=true;
    do{
      System.out.println("What is your prefered ticket price?");
      ticketprice=kb.nextInt();
      while (row<seats.length && !found){
        do{
          if(seats[row][col] == ticketprice){
            found = true;}
          else{
            col++; }  // this line, in the last iteration, will make col=seats[0].length
        }while(col<seats[0].length &&!found);
        if(seats[row][col] == ticketprice){ //col with value greater than it should.
          found = true;}
        else{
          row++;} 
      }
      if(found){
        seats[row][col] = 0; }
      else {
        System.out.println("Seat not found at specified price.");
        seatavaliable=false;}
    }while(seatavaliable==false);

    return seats;
  }
```

Comment: Instead of using seats.length and seats[0].length I created constants to work instead with the intention that the final iteration would make col<seats[0].length. This is giving me the same error, but am I headed in the right direction or should I change that block of code entirely?

Comment: If you update the value of col, then sees it is greater than the maximum value and use again the value of col, it will be out of bounds. No matter if using the array length or a constant.

Comment: I changed the inside do..while to a while and added a line after the first while saying 'col=0;' which seemed to fix the problem.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `nextInt()` method leaves the `\n` (end line) symbol and is picked up immediately by `nextLine()`, skipping over the next input.  What you want to do is use `nextLine()` for everything, and parse it later:

```
String nextIntString = keyboard.nextLine(); //get the number as a single line
int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString); //convert the string to an int
```

This is by far the easiest way to avoid problems--don't mix your "next" methods.  Use only `nextLine()` and then parse `int`s or separate words afterwards.

---

You cannot close another `Scanner` because it then closes the underlying `InputStream`, therefore the first `Scanner` can no longer read from the same `InputStream` and you get a `NoSuchElementException`.

---

Last note: you should always close a `Scanner` when you are done with it to conserve system resources.

Comment: How do you close a Scanner?

Comment: For your code, `kb.close()`, when you are done using **1** `Scanner`.